# Springboot Email listening using IMAPs

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, gmail, microservices

I am thinking to create a microservice where I will listen to the emails and by listening to those emails I will create a JSON object based on my requirements. for this requirement I am thinking to use spring boot and imps can u provide the way of logic to implement my requirement. there are many examples in google to send mail by using spring boot. but there are no proper examples are there in order to read emails and create JSON object. Thanks in Advance for your solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some documentation for inbound emails on spring
https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mail.html#mail-inbound

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/test/mail/MailTests.java

Comment: @defrmhsn can u give realtime example or links

Comment: @AkhilNallapaneni This one looks promising https://github.com/voodoodyne/subethasmtp 
Also here is an example how to use it 
https://medium.com/@dmarko484/spring-boot-listening-for-incoming-emails-in-our-applications-aeec2b4b7876

Comment: @defrmhsn i want to use imaps instead of smtps